# Implementing Html.DropDownListFor() in View Only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am completely new to Asp.Net (junior dev). I'm working on a project that requires a customer to enter data to be stored in a database. When I created the template view for the model, I get a EditorFor() textbox for the customer to enter data. Here's what it looked like:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantState, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantState, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantState, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

This works great, except I want the user to choose from a drop-down list of options rather than enter the data themselves. Here's what I want to do if I were doing the dropdown list with straight HTML:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantState, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select id="applicantState">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- Please Select --  </option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I need to get this data to store in the ApplicantState field in the model. The senior developer running this project **does NOT want me to add code to the model or controller to do this; he wants me to do the drop-down list in the view only.**

Here's what I have...

```
             <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantState, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ApplicantState, new List<SelectListItem> {
                              new SelectListItem { Value = "" , Text = " -- Please Select --  "  },
                              new SelectListItem { Value = "OH", Text = "Ohio"},
                              new SelectListItem { Value = "CA", Text = "California"},
                              new SelectListItem { Value = "TX", Text = "Texas"}
                            })
                  </div>
              </div>
```

The code is compiling and I'm not getting any errors. For anyone who's done this before, does this look correct? Will the dropdown list option be stored in the ApplicantState field? I have no confidence in what I've written. I've only ever done a dropdown list from a MVC controller. I'm not yet able to test the code by submitting a fake application. The view is popping up correctly though. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Code reviews belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), not SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this:

> The senior developer running this project does NOT want me to add code to the model or controller to do this; he wants me to do the drop-down list in the view only.

You need to instantiate at the top of your Razor view this dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "OH", "Ohio"},
    { "CA", "California"},
    { "TX", "Texas"}
};
```

Then replace your razor code with this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicantState, dictionary.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.Key, Text = d.Value }).ToList(), " -- Please Select --  ");
```

This is clean and should work. After that you need to tell to your co-worker that the dictionary which keep the data should belong to your model and the code should go there.

Comment: You do not need to do this and its just unnecessary extra overhead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  But his senior developer doesn't like to put SelectListItem and other things related to the dropdown list into the model. So I think a dictionary which hold the data that may come from a database should go to the model.

Comment: Its hard coded values! And to claim a 'senior' developer told them to do this is nonsense - any one suggesting to do it in the view is barely a developer, let alone a 'senior' one

Comment: Questions posted in SO are never a full/complete project. just because he hardcoded doesn't mean it will be the case in his real project. ;-) Who is going to hard code a whole list of cities? Sorry not me. So I let the OP answer this question and give us more details.

Comment: If it were coming from a database, then to do it in a view would make even less sense :)

Comment: I don't get it :) You mean If I have a service that give me a list of cities I can code the call to that service inside my Razor view. Sorry I don't think you mean that but can you explain in detail please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152206/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-codenotfound).